# php UPDATE and SELECT in same query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to make a double query in php and doesn't work for some reason.

Basicall I want to update a row in my table where the id is MAX and the fb_id it's equal to fbId parameter.

Here is my code:

```
  public function updatePages($fbId, $nr_page = NULL) {
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $query = "UPDATE visits SET pages =".$nr_page." WHERE id = (SELECT maxvalue FROM (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxvalue FROM visits WHERE fb_id =".$fbId."))";
        if($db->query($query))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you test the query in MySQL (workbench, command line) already? That might tell you an issue with the query.

Comment: I didn't try, I don't have it installed.

Comment: Please go and try the query: It makes your debugging process way more efficient.

Comment: basically I want to update the biggest id in the table, I will try and install it

Comment: Is this PDO or `mysqli`? If so, you **really** need to look into using prepared statements.

Comment: is PDO, well after I figure out the query I can implement and prepared statemetns for security.

Comment: It's usually best to do things correctly the first time so you don't spend hours chasing down a bug caused by bad quoting or something like that. If you want to experiment with the query itself, do that outside of PHP by using the `mysql` shell or Workbench tool directly.

Comment: True, I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to `SELECT` max of id and assign to `id` of `WHERE` clause

```
$query = "UPDATE visits SET pages =".$nr_page." WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxvalue FROM visits WHERE fb_id =".$fbId." LIMIT 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need two levels? Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE visits SET pages =".$nr_page." WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM visits WHERE fb_id =".$fbId." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: Nope, it says "General error: 1903 You can't specify target table 'visits' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I found it finally, was similar to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work finally, here is the solution:

```
  $query = "UPDATE visits SET pages =".$nr_page." WHERE fb_id =".$fbId." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```